# Argument 'x' passed to 'slice2d' must be numeric tensor, but got string tensor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

Upon training the model with model.fit() the following error occurs:

```
/mnt/d/projects/detect-license-plate-autoixpert/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:5481
        throw new Error("Argument '".concat(argName, "' passed to '").concat(functionName, "' must ") +
              ^

Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'slice2d' must be numeric tensor, but got string tensor
    at assertDtype (/mnt/d/projects/detect-license-plate-autoixpert/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:5481:15)
```

I'm trying to create a machine learning model that detects licence plates on images. Therefore I try to train the model with an imageTensor:

```json
    Tensor {
      kept: false,
      isDisposedInternal: false,
      shape: [ 179 ],
      dtype: 'float32',
      size: 179,
      strides: [],
      dataId: { id: 724 },
      id: 1448,
      rankType: '1'
    }
```

and a labelTensor:

```json
    Tensor {
      kept: false,
      isDisposedInternal: false,
      shape: [ 179 ],
      dtype: 'string',
      size: 179,
      strides: [],
      dataId: { id: 725 },
      id: 1449,
      rankType: '1'
    }
```

Here is the function:

```js
    const trainingImageTensor = tf.tensor(featureImages);
     const trainingLabelTensor = tf.tensor(featureLabels);
    
     console.log(trainingImageTensor);
     console.log(trainingLabelTensor);
    
     const result = await model.fit(trainingImageTensor, trainingLabelTensor, {
                shuffle: true,
                batchSize       : 32,
                epochs          : 100,
                validationSplit : 0.5,
                callbacks: {
                    onEpochEnd: logProgress
      }
     });
```